# Covariance between estimated random effects $\hat{\boldsymbol{b}}$ and real idiosyncratic error vector $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$ in a Linear Mixed Model

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, covariance, regression-analysis

Let us assume a linear mixed model of the form

$$
\boldsymbol{y} = \boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{Z}\boldsymbol{b} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}
$$

where $\boldsymbol{X}$ is the fixed-effect design matrix, $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ the fixed-effect coefficient vector, $\boldsymbol{Z}$ a block-diagonal random-effect design matrix, $\boldsymbol{b}$ the corresponding random effects and $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$ the idiosyncratic error vector. As usual, the idiosyncratic errors are assumed i.i.d. and the random effects are distributed according to covariance matrix $\boldsymbol{Q}$.

$$\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_i\left|\boldsymbol{X}_i \sim \mathrm{N}\left(\mathbf{0}, \sigma^2 \boldsymbol{I}_{n_i}\right), \quad \boldsymbol{b}_i\right| \boldsymbol{X_i} \sim \mathrm{N}(\mathbf{0}, \boldsymbol{Q})$$

Based on these assumptions, we obtain the full idiosyncratic error matrix $\boldsymbol{Q}$ and the full random effect covariance matrix $\boldsymbol{D}$ and $\boldsymbol{V}$, which is  the covariance matrix of $\boldsymbol{y}$.

$$\boldsymbol{R}=\operatorname{blockdiag}\left(\sigma^2 \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{n_1}, \ldots, \sigma^2 \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{n_i}, \ldots, \sigma^2 \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{n_m}\right)$$

$$\boldsymbol{D}=\operatorname{blockdiag}(\boldsymbol{Q}, \ldots, \boldsymbol{Q}, \ldots, \boldsymbol{Q})$$

$$
\left(\begin{array}{l}
\boldsymbol{b} \\
\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}
\end{array}\right) \sim \mathrm{N}\left(\left(\begin{array}{l}
\boldsymbol{0} \\
\boldsymbol{0}
\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{ll}
\boldsymbol{D} & \boldsymbol{0} \\
\boldsymbol{0} & \boldsymbol{R}
\end{array}\right)\right)
$$

$$\quad$$

$$\boldsymbol{V}=\boldsymbol{R}+\boldsymbol{Z} \boldsymbol{D} \boldsymbol{Z}^{\prime}$$

Unbiased estimates of the random effects can then be obtained according to

$$
\hat{\boldsymbol{b}} = \boldsymbol{\hat{D}}\boldsymbol{Z}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{V^{-1}}(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}})
$$

$$\quad$$

I am interested in the covariance matrix of the estimated random-effect vector $\boldsymbol{b}$ and the unobservable idiosyncratic error vector $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$, i.e. I want to obtain

$$
Cov[\hat{\boldsymbol{b}}, \boldsymbol{\epsilon}]
$$

So far I tried the following

$$
Cov[\hat{\boldsymbol{b}}, \boldsymbol{\epsilon}] = 
E[(\boldsymbol{\hat{b}} - E[\boldsymbol{\hat{b}}])(\boldsymbol{\epsilon} - \boldsymbol{0})^{\prime}] = E\left[\left(\boldsymbol{\hat{D}}\boldsymbol{Z}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{V^{-1}}(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}) - \boldsymbol{b}\right)\boldsymbol{\epsilon}^{\prime}\right] = 
$$
$$
E\left[\left(\boldsymbol{\hat{D}}\boldsymbol{Z}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{V^{-1}}\boldsymbol{y}-
\boldsymbol{\hat{D}}\boldsymbol{Z}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{V^{-1}}\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}\right)\boldsymbol{\epsilon}^{\prime} - \boldsymbol{b}\boldsymbol{\epsilon}^{\prime} \right] = E\left[\left(\boldsymbol{\hat{D}}\boldsymbol{Z}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{V^{-1}}\boldsymbol{y}-
\boldsymbol{\hat{D}}\boldsymbol{Z}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{V^{-1}}\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}\right)\boldsymbol{\epsilon}^{\prime}\right] 
$$

I do not know how to continue from here and I am even not quite sure if I got everything right until here.

Could anybody help me out? I would greatly appreciate your help!